# laravel one to many relationship return no error

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I try to create a relationship between user and post. 1 user have many posts and 1 post has 1 user. I already write a code relationship between model User.php and Post.php and I want to store user data in database. my question is how to save data in database? btw I use postgresql. when I click button there is no error and cannot redirect to admin.post.index.

PostController.php

```
public function store(Request $request)
{    
    $user = auth()->user();
    $post = $user->posts()->create($request->only('title','body'));
    return redirect()->route('admin.post.index');
}
```

Post.php

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

User.php

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasmany('App\Post');
}
```

Comment: Typo? `hasmany` vs. `hasMany`. Nothing in your logs? What does `dd($post)` say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Change User.php

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
}
```

you spelled incorrect

Answer (score 1):

**You can try to Change User.php**

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Post','user_id');
}
```